# Character limit on Title column

Tags: wss-3.0, column

I would like to know if there is a way to increase the character limit of 255 chars on the Title column of a list.

[image: character limit]

If not, is there any way to bypass the Title (is a required field by default) and add a text area instead with an item menu attached to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a list, you can follow these steps:

1) Go to List settings > Advanced Settings > Allow Management of Content Types = Yes

2) Click on the content type (e.g. Item)

3) Click on Title column and select Hidden

Bear in mind that removing (hiding) the title is like shooting yourself in the foot.

SharePoint uses a weighted ranking search model and the Title carries the highest weight.
Effectively, you are hurting your search results.

Just add a new field called "Description" if you need more space.

Comment: Hmm I was not aware of the weighted ranking thing.. This messes up everything as we keep the whole archive basically for SP's search feature. I'm afraid I'm gonna have to keep the built-in Title column and fill it with a summary of the full title, just for the search engine to work.. Thanks

Comment: Although I totally agree with your comment, I just need to clarify that searching will continue to work. It is just that the Title is the single most important factor for the search engine, so removing it you are reducing the effectiveness of the search engine.

Comment: Dont worry, I understood you completely. I just need the search to work at its best as the size of the archive is enormous with many similar records.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum character limit for "Single line of text" column is 255, ie why you cannot increase character limit for Title column. You can create another column which will be a Multi line text column(will support more than 255 chars), and you have to attach  "Linked to item" option to that column.For that you will have to edit the default view of the List in SharePoint Designer and add the below line in the **ViewFields** section of **XsltListViewWebPart**

```
<FieldRef Name="ColumnName" linkToItem="TRUE"  />
```

Comment: So, there is no way to change the type for the Title column to "multi line text"? The solution you suggest is what I had in mind as alternative, but the main problem is I cant prevent the old Title column to appear on forms, cause its a required field by default..

Comment: @LePhleg i don't think you can change title column to multi line text. You need not hide the old title column, you can still show title column and another column(linked to item) in a view.

Comment: yes but having 2 fields for the Title (one for the original built-in column and one for the new multi-line text) would create a bunch of duplicate information which I want to avoid.. It would be nice If I could get rid of the old Title column entirely.

Comment: @LePhleg how many items were there previously.you can try writing script to copy old title column to new title column

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following article for 2010. You might be using 2007 so you can check whether it is applicable to your case or not.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6bfa6ec8-c784-4dea-9e03-73e5afaebfa8/how-to-add-sharepoint-context-menu-on-a-custom-column-of-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: Please do not provide link-only answers. Instead add some details from the link and use it as merely a source

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Robert. I will take care of this from next time.

Comment: I would prefer if you did it also on this post :)