# Decrease Title Character Limit

Tags: 2013, column

I know it's not possible to increase the maximum length of the title column.

[Character limit on Title column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/character-limit-on-title-column)

However, what would be the easiest way to decrease it to 50 Characters, for example? I'm trying to avoid the custom form route.
Is there anything I could do through XML definitions that would allow this?

Comment: Go into the list properties and set the title field to 50?

Comment: Haha, I guess I didn't phrase it properly. Can I do it through something like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx   `MaxLength` in the list definition?

Comment: If you are provisioning a list through a feature or app, you can set those properties when you are building it or in an event receiver on feature activation to set the maxlength property.

Comment: Figured as much, was hoping to avoid that.